# Is there a good option for creation of custom branching rules in branch-and-bound for MILPs in Python?

Tags: python, linear-programming, integer-programming, branch-and-bound

Basically, I want to recreate the conceptual results from the paper "Learning to Branch in Mixed Integer Programming" by Khalil, et al, at the same time avoiding, if possible:

1)The necessity of obtaining an academic license for CPLEX (which was used in the paper) or similar serious commercial solver

2)The necessity of using C based API. This is not a strict requirement, but Python has the benefit of having good and very accessible ML libraries, which seems like a great advantage for this specific goal

I am aware, that there is a great number of open source Python based MILP solvers, but a lot of them focus on the end-to-end solution of relatively simple problems in their presentation and, if we also consider, that a lot of them (if not all) hook up to other C based solvers, it is highly non-obvious to judge, which ones actually have needed customization potential.

So, if anyone has more in-depth experience with trying to customize Python solvers for their highly specific needs, I would appreciate the advice.

Comment: CPLEX has a Python API. And if your model does not have more than 1000 variables or constraints then you can use the community edition of CPLEX which is *completely* free of charge and for which you don't have to enroll in the academic initiative either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you will hit a roadblock at some point there. It's really hard to do that without doing C/C++ work (imho).

## Python-way

**I only know three projects with some low-level functionality** (and it's still hard to say if those fit your needs).

- **https://github.com/coin-or/python-mip**

  - relatively new
  - promises interactive cut-gen
  - has a chapter [Developing Customized Branch-&-Cut algorithms](https://python-mip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom.html)
  - **but** i'm not sure if there is enough freedom for your task (seems to focus on cuts for now)
  - build around open-source solver Cbc/Clp (besides Gurobi)
- **https://github.com/coin-or/CyLP**

  - not much develeopment for years now

    - the whole python-3 dev was sad (see issues; pull-request not processed for years; it's a resource problem: the maintainers are nice people!)
  - was designed to research pivoting
  - but it also says: `For example, you may
    .. define cut generators, branch-and-bound strategies`

    - hard to see how to achieve what you look for except for abstract LP-relax - fix - resolve
    - might be hard to control specifics (warm-start vs. hot-start)
    - build around open-source Cbc/Clp
- **https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt**

  - basic docs show more high-level usage
  - but it's internal code at least has entries for `branchexeclp` and co.

    - maybe it's ready to use (maybe not)
    - [raw list of interface classes](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/tree/1b2c1a8dd82ac3e7358fa87b629d3810274631f0/src/pyscipopt)
    - as those things (maybe) wrap the original C-API, there is a lot of good documentation in the parent-project!
  - build around open-source solver [SCIP](https://scip.zib.de/)
  - easier to grab the solver in academic setting, but by no means *free* (i'm not a lawyer and won't try to find the right words)
  - at least one developer of it is active on StackOverflow

## Alternative: C++

If trying to get full-control; which might be needed, with minimal need for understanding the underlying solver in all it's details, you probably want to use C/C++ within [Coin OSI](https://github.com/coin-or/Osi). Sadly the *Cbc* part is unmaintained, but depending on your exact task, you might only need *Clp* for example.

## Alternative: Julia

I did not follow the recent developments there, but the language did have a strong early focus on Mathematical Optimization (driven by a big group of people) surpassing python even in it's early days (imho!).

But i'm not sure if [MathOptInterface](http://www.juliaopt.org/MathOptInterface.jl/dev/) is fine-grained enough for your task.

Comment: Here is an example of a branching-rule implementation in PySCIPOpt: https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/tests/test_branch_probing_lp.py